# Java GUI Swing Text Field

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*; 
public class Test {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        JDialog frame = new JDialog();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea("Hi");
        frame.add(text);
    }
}
```

Why does a text area not appear? I'm trying to learn Java Swing. I just see a blank Dialog, also, a website explaining all the JComponents would help

Comment: There are tutorials on oracle's site with such tutorials. Or you could google "java swing tutorials."

Answer (score 0):

`setVisible` after adding the `JTextArea`:

```
import javax.swing.*; 

public class Test {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        JDialog frame = new JDialog();
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea("Hi");
        frame.add(text);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

OR

`validate` after adding the `JTextArea`, if the `frame` is already visible:

import javax.swing.*;

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        JDialog frame = new JDialog();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea("Hi");
        frame.add(text);
        frame.validate();
    }
}
```